# Copy and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, copy

I have a doubt about the copy assignment and pointers.

I will show it as an example:

```
class Abc 
{      
public:
  Abc() { q = new Qwe;}
  Qwe* GetQwe() { return q; }

private:

  Qwe* q;
};

Abc* a = new Abc();
Qwe* aux = a->GetQwe();
aux->Modify();
```

I don't know if when I call GetQwe, it is returning a copy of the value of q but not in the same memory position as q.

So my question is, would the q from Abc be modified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is, would the q from Abc be modified?

No `q` itself will not be modified, `GetQwe()` will return copy of pointer that still points to the same memory location as `q`, but object both `q` and `aux` are pointing is the same and can be modified by `Modify()` call. Althru you need to initialize `Abc::q` prior to calls its member functions.

Answer (score 3):

It returns a copy of the pointer. This copy points to the same object in memory to which the original pointer `q` points. So, pointer `q` will not be modified, BUT `pointee` will.

Answer (score 1):

`GetQwe()` returns a pointer (address) to the Qwe object. Therefore your pointer `aux` is pointing to the same object as `p` and so the call to Modify will change that single object. To have a copy then lose the * like this:

```
Qwe GetQweCopy() { return *p; }
```